# Centering nested divs

Tags: css, html, centering

Once again I'm having issues centering divs...

http://www.srcf.ucam.org/~sas98/project.php

How would I go about centering everything in #main?

Comment: Do you have text-align:center set in the main div?

Comment: It's the `width: 100%;` that keeping your `div#main` from centering in the browser window. Give it a pixel width and it should center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center `<div class="main">` (and it *is* a `class` - that means it's `.main`, not `#main` - your HTML and CSS do not agree with each other on this point):

- Add `margin: 0 auto; width: 1020px` to `.main`. `1020px` is the right number to use here.
- You also need to remove `width: 100%` from `body`, or your centering will not be precisely correct.
- You should also remove `overflow: hidden` from `body`, or scrolling is impossible on your page.

Lastly, add a proper doctype as the *very first line*, or your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and you'll in particular have big problems with Internet Explorer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I'm not sure what your footer is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 3):

try: `margin: 0 auto; display: table`
No width needed, nothing. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Worked wonderfully in Chrome and IE for a responsive-web-design site I was working on.  Thank you @Cosmin.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use doctype for your HTML -

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
2. second - add to main class this :

   `margin: 0 auto;`

EDIT:
And make main width in pixels

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the correct doctype.

The key to centering using `margin: 0 auto;` is making sure that the same div has a static width.

```
 #main { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
```