# RWD: Center nested DIVs

Tags: css, styles, responsive-design, css-float, html

Please bear with me - CSS and RWD is quite new to me (a javascript, c++, python person).

I'm trying to center a nested DVI on a RWD (responsive web design page) for a friend.

The code looks like:

```
<div id="homewrapper" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="section" id="homeleftcol" style="overflow: hidden; margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 7px; text-align: left; clear: left; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
    <a title="365x522" href="/a/"><img  style="padding: 0px;" alt="" src="black.png" width="356" height="522" /></a>
    <div class="hometitle" id="imgtitle">365x522</div>
</div>
<div id="homerightcol" style="clear: none; float: left;">
    <div class="section" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 7px; margin-bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;">
        <a title="365x254" href="/b/"><img  style="padding: 0px;" alt="" src="yellow.png" /></a>
        <div class="hometitle" id="imgtitle">365x254</div>
    </div>
    <div id="learncontact" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="section" id="learn" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 7px; overflow: hidden; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
            <a title="172x254" href="/c/"><img  style="padding: 0px;" alt="" src="blue.png" width="171" height="254" /></a>
            <div class="hometitle" id="imgtitle">172x254</div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="contact" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 7px; overflow: hidden; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
            <a title="172x254" href="/d/"><img style="padding: 0px;" alt="" src="red.png" width="171" height="254" /></a>
            <div class="hometitle" id="imgtitle">172x254</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have a mostly ok solution but when the page is enlarged the DIVs hug the left side.

```
Wide: Hugs the margin-left:7px
```

[image: Home - Wide]

Here are a few other views (you can see it still hugs to the left but the images scale to fit for the most part.

[image: Normal]

[image: Narrow]

[image: VeryNarrow]

Your help is *greatly* appreciated!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout hugs the right side of the page because you have not set a width-value to the "homewrapper" div. The question [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally) covers this problem in more detail.

This could be fixed by giving it a total width value like so:

```
<div id="homewrapper" style="width: 744px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

However there are some other issues with your code. I don't know if you already are aware of this, but you say that you are new to CSS, so I'll include it anyway.

Writing all of your styling directly in the style attribute of a html tag is considered very bad style and counteracts the benefits of separating content and presentation. You should instead include it in a separate style sheet and include it in the header of the html-document. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) will show you the way to enlightenment.

Comment: Wow - thank you @Teodor for both tips.  I will make a separate style sheet.  I did have some margins/padding so I needed to make the width a tad larger: 760px.  However; when I shrink the page to less than 760px the _homerightcol_ drops below _homeleftcol_ but is not visible anymore as _homewrapper_ height does not grow.  If I set the height: 1200px for _homewrapper_ there is just white below; where did _homerightcol_ go?

Comment: Using <div id="homewrapper" style="margin:0 auto; display:table;"> seems to work.  I tracked that down at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311471/centering-nested-divs   I will need to test on FF and IE to see how it works.

Comment: Nice to hear that the tips worked for you. RWD is an art, so a bit of tweaking to get things right is normal. As you get more confident with css you'll probably want to use a framework to handle the layout. http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/ has a nice breakdown of some of the most used ones.